# Conditional Binding Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

I've found some questions here about this topic, but none of the solutions solve my problem.
I need to bind a property on a control only if a checkbox is checked. I've seen people suggesting to create a Converter for this, but I can't access the state of a control in the converter. The only way I know is doing it on the code behind. Does any one know any other way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Silverlight3, you might want to check out [Element Binding](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-%E2%80%93-ui-element-to-element-binding)

Comment: Hi... But how can I make this? How can I activate or deactivate a binding depending on other control state?

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario for this requirement (but i'm not very imaginative :) ) - can you tell us more details on what you need to do? Maybe there is another, simpler way to accomplish it...

Comment: I have a C1NumericBox control and the minimum value is bound to another C1NumericBox that can be enabled and disabled by a checkbox. the minimu value needs to be bound only if the other numeric box is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using WPF I would suggest a multi-binding, but unfortunately this isn't supported on Silverlight, even on SL5.

However, this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5) adds multi-binding support through a markup extension, so you may be able to find a solution using that.